# Trigger help function (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.0.32.

I have two tables: `UserItemVote` and `ItemStat`.

`UserItemVote` has:

```
user_id, item_id, vote(tinyint either 0 for downvote or 1 for upvote)
```

`ItemStat` has:

```
item_id, total_up_vote, total_down_vote
```

When the user vote up/down an item (insert to UserItemVote table), 
I want to have a trigger `tai_UserItemVote` to update either 
`total_up_vote` or `total_down_vote` from `ItemStat`.

So far, I have only worked out the update trigger but not the insert trigger.

`tai_UserItemVote` insert trigger:

```
// insert to itemstat if row not exist otherwise update itemstat.
```

`tau_UserItemVote` update trigger:

```
UPDATE ItemStat set total_down_vote=total_down_vote+1 
WHERE item_id=NEW.item_id and NEW.vote = 0;  
UPDATE ItemStat set total_up_vote=total_up_vote+1 
WHERE item_id=NEW.item_id and NEW.vote = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) should do what you need.